# c# - Multicast - System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10042)

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

Running this code on windows 10/11 using .NET 7.0 or any previous framework I got exception on line  :

```
s.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.AddMembership, new MulticastOption(ip, IPAddress.Any));
```

```
Unhandled exception. System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10042): An unknown, invalid, or unsupported option or level was specified in a getsockopt or setsockopt call.
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UpdateStatusAfterSocketErrorAndThrowException(SocketError error, Boolean disconnectOnFailure, String callerName)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.SetMulticastOption(SocketOptionName optionName, MulticastOption MR)
   at MainClass.Main(String[] args)
```

```
string IpGroup = "224.0.224.1";
string sPort = "2405";

Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, int.Parse(sPort));
s.Bind(ipep);

IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(IpGroup);

try
{
//Error HERE    
s.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.AddMembership, new MulticastOption(ip, IPAddress.Any));
    Console.WriteLine("Joined: " + IpGroup + ":" + sPort);
    while (true)
    {

    byte[] b = new byte[100];

    s.Receive(b);
    string str = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(b, 0, b.Length);

    Console.WriteLine("RX: " + str.Trim());

    }
}
catch (Exception err)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ERR:" + err.Message);
}
```

Same code running on Windows 7 or on Linux arm 32 run without problem.

Someone can help me ?

Comment: May not be helpful, but your code runs fine on my Win10 machine. So it's probably not Windows itself that's the issue.   Win10 22H2 9045.2486, .NET SDK 7.0.2

Comment: do you tested it on your system ?

Comment: I did, and it runs fine. Have you tried it on a *different* Win10 machine?